How to solve "WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000'" error nginx
I am trying to follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J8xReLuBNPY&list=PL0Zuz27SZ-6NOkbTDxKi7grs_oxJhLu07&index=1 on making a chat application with NodeJS and websockets. I am able to access my webpage through https://my.site because it is hosted with nginx and I have an ssl certificate, but when I go to this address there is an error that says: "WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000" in the console. This is my first time using websockets so any help is appreciated.
I tried adding
location / {
    # redirect all HTTP traffic to localhost:8080
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    # WebSocket support
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}

to my nginx config file but it resulted in the error Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xeu nginx.service" for details. failed! 

It's 3000, right? Not 8080.  I just made a similar node app but I used express for the server.  I don't know about nginx very well.

@JayCravens Yea, it is 3000. I tried changing the port number but it still didn't work, I got this error Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xeu nginx.service" for details. failed! when I tried to restart nginx.

Is nginx mandatory?
